# API URI design nested vs query string

Tags: rest, api, uri, api-design

From Microsoft's API design guidance(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#more-information):

> In more complex systems, it can be tempting to provide URIs that enable a client to navigate through several levels of relationships, such as `/customers/1/orders/99/products`. However, this level of complexity can be difficult to maintain and is inflexible if the relationships between resources change in the future. Instead, try to keep URIs relatively simple. Once an application has a reference to a resource, it should be possible to use this reference to find items related to that resource. The preceding query can be replaced with the URI `/customers/1/orders` to find all the orders for customer 1, and then `/orders/99/products` to find the products in this order.
>
> Avoid requiring resource URIs more complex than collection/item/collection.

From Microsoft's example, let's say I want to find all the products of customer 1. Then I would need to first query `/customers/1/orders` to find all the orders then query **individual orders by** `/orders/{id}/products` which falls into N+1 problem. Also, If I want to create a new order, should I `POST` to `/customers/1/order` or `/orders` with `customer_id`?

```
//2 endpoints
/customers/1/orders
/orders/{id}/products //for n orders
```

Or I could build all APIs with 1 depth and search for all the products by `/products/?customer_id=1`

```
//3 endpoints
/customers
/orders
/products
```

To sum up,

1. which would be better approach? nested vs 1depth but more endpoint
2. If nested is better, with microsoft's example, if I want to create a new order for customer 1, should i `POST` to `/customers/1/orders` or `/orders` with `customer_id` in body or support both?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are okay from a REST API design perspective. You should design it according to your use case and to increase the developer experience:

- If it's more intuitive to create an order in a customer context, choose a nested approach.
- If it's more intuitive to create an order and send the customer id as an attribute of the order object, choose the other approach.

You can even serve both approaches, as the API is just an interface to communicate with your service (just like a GUI, but for m2m purposes).